# Does the Chrome API let me cast a tab without user interaction?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromecast

I'm looking to build a Chrome extension that will run on a schedule, casting a URL to a Chromecast at a specific time of day. It's important that it can cast a tab without requiring the user to do anything. Assuming the user has granted the necessary permissions, is it possible to cast a tab to a tab without requiring the user to confirm any sort of prompt?

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, it's a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Comment: @Makyen What would be a more appropriate way to phrase it? I think it's pretty clear what I'm asking.

Comment: That depends on what you're wanting to know. Do you *really* want to know "is it possible"? Or, are you really wanting to know "How can I cast a URL to a Chromecast?" (Note that the "at a specific time of day" would make it too broad, as that would be effectively asking multiple questions ("How do I do X" and "How do I do something at a particular time of day"). Also note that you have not stated any initial conditions and the assumptions you've made in your question, which also makes it too broad (e.g. does the user already have Chromecast set up/any extensions assumed to be installed, etc.).

Comment: Importantly, you should describe the research you've already done on the subject. For instance, there appear to be various extensions/applications which do much of what you desire. In addition, stating if you are limiting your questions strictly to *only* a Chrome extension, or if a solution which is a Chrome extension connecting to a native application is also a viable solution.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if it's ultimately possible (assuming the user has configured everything and granted Chrome permissions) to cast a tab without any sort of prompt that would restrict the complete automation of this step. I included the description of the extension for context rather than for answers on how to build it.

Comment: Chrome's policy is to require actual user actions for such stuff.